# Regex string does not contain dot

Tags: c#, regex

I need to write the following Regex (C#) - input string does not contain a dot (.) character. How can I do it?

P.S. I have access only to RegEx. I cannot use "string.Contains" method (API of third-party application).  That's why I asked how to do it with regex

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try? Show us your code so we can see what's wrong with it. This is a very basic task. You might want to start with regular expression tutorials like http://www.regular-expression.info

Comment: Please do more research on your own before asking a question, and let us know what you've done and where you're stuck. See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you could use a simple `string.contains()`, you don't need a regex.

Comment: XY problem detected, X is still unknown, Y is the regex

Comment: Regex '.' is a wildcard character, so you need to escape the '.' character, with a backslash will do it.

Comment: Why use regex? Just use `!string.Contains(".")`

Comment: I have access only to RegEx. I cannot use "string.Contains" method (API of third-party application).  That's why I asked how to do it with regex

Comment: Why so many downvotes? This isn't a bad question it needs to use a negated character classes [^.] this is not trivial for non regex user.

Comment: @and.maz can you put sample data for your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the below regex which don't allow a dot character,

```
^[^.]+$
```

Example:

```
String s = "0787654321";
if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[^.]+$")) {
Console.WriteLine("Correct format");
}
else {
Console.WriteLine("Error! Wrong format.");
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ZsvjE9)

Comment: There is no need to escape the dot within `[]` brackets

Answer (score 0):

Your whole text is (from beginning `^` to end `$`) any number of characters (`*`), but no dots (`[^\.]`):

```
^[^.]*$
```

As @TheLostMind points out, `string.Contains` is easier:

```
!input.Contains(".");
```

Comment: You don't have to escape the dot inside `[]`.

Comment: @atornblad It doesn't make any difference but I have still removed it.

Comment: it matches an empty string also.

Comment: @AvinashRaj well, an empty string doesn't contain a dot, does it? I think it should be matched as well if the requirement only is `input string does not contain a dot (.) character`